# firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged return user null

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement authentification using firebase auth, the things is that when it comes to persistance i'm stuck.
I tried to use local storage as you can see below :

**AuthService.ts :**

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  userData: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.firebaseAuth.useEmulator('http://localhost:9099');
    this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    });
    this.firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged( user => {
      console.log(user);
    });
  }



  signIn(email: string, password: string): void {
    this.firebaseAuth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL).then(() => {
      this.firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(result => {
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/accueil']);
          console.log('Nice, it worked!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('Something went wrong:', error.message);
        });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('Something went wrong:', error.message);
    });
  }

  signOut(): void {
    this.firebaseAuth.signOut().then(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/connexion']);
    });
  }

  forgetPassword(email: string): void {
    this.firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(() => {
      window.alert('Password reset email sent, check your inbox.');
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error);
    });
  }

  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user !== null) ? true : false;
  }


}
```

But the problem is that firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged return null after refreshing the page with **F5** even authState. It's like onAuthStateChange is losing his last state after refresh.

***Note that i'm using firebase Emulator.***

**app.module.ts**
Firebase module has been well import

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
AngularFireAuthModule,
```

You can take a look at the confing here :
**environnement.ts**

```
 firebase: {
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    projectId: 'xxxx'
  }
```

Maybe it's link to this **error** that i'm getting in the web console when i'm refreshing the page :

POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key=xxxxxxx 400

Note that key is equal to my apiKey state in the config.

When i look closer here what the error say :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_ID_TOKEN",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_ID_TOKEN",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

**EDIT**

Here what i get after refresh my page from onAuthStateChanged :
[image]

There is no 2 calls, only 1 that return false.

Comment: It is the expected behavior that an `onAuthStateChanged` gets called with `null` when a page loads, as Firebase needs to call to the server to check the user credentials. When that successfully completes, it again calls your `onAuthStateChanged` listener with the signed in user.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen   Ok, but why at the end it's still null ? even after the page has been loaded. I can't see any new call of my onAuthStateChanged, and what happen is that, i'm disconnected after a 2nde refresh because the last value store was a user null so AuthGuard redirect me to the connexion page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Auth will persist the login state by default, so you don't have to manually save the token into local storage. As Frank said, onAuthStateChanged will fire will user being null initially, but if the user is signed in, it will fire again shortly after that with the actual user value.

Comment: From what i see in the console, it never fire again, so at the end i'm being redirected by AuthGuard because the last value storage was a user null

Comment: @JeremyDormevil Remove `.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)`. `.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)` makes the token expire in an hour.

Comment: Even when i set it to LOCAL, there is no 2nde call of onAuthStateChanged, why ?

Comment: @JeremyDormevil Did you delete all the code that's related to local storage?

Comment: Yep but it doesn't change anything because the problem it's that onAuthStateChanged is not call 2 time as  Frank is saying that it should behave but only 1.

Comment: I updated my post with what i got from the console after the refresh

Comment: @JeremyDormevil What happens if you remove `this.firebaseAuth.useEmulator('http://localhost:9099');`? Maybe it's an emulator problem. Also, is the code above the most up to date code? I still see some localStorage related code.

Comment: I just want to make sure localStorage related code are not interfering in any way with the auth code.

Comment: It works, it was just the emulator that doesn't seem to behave well, but when it comes to testing directly, there is indeed 2 call, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Following to the comment section of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65536273/826983), I decided to highlight the fact that this appears to be en emulator issue.

This was driving me crazy. No matter what I did, even jumping up and down, the `currentUser` was always `null`. I saw the same behavior: `onAuthStateChanged()` got called only once and all I got was a `null`-user.

After removing my provider for the Auth-emulator, everything started to work without issues.

```js
  providers: [

    // ...
    { provide: REGION, useValue: envFirebase.region},

    // THE PROBLEM:
    {
        provide: USE_AUTH_EMULATOR, 
        useValue: envFirebase.useEmulators ? ['http://localhost:9099'] : undefined
    },
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you experience this with emulator, adding "signInFlow: 'popup'" to the firebaseui config solved it for me.